# Using Jquery Mobile to create charts using d3js with fixed width

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, svg, d3.js

I am creating Charts for Mobile Devices using [d3js](http://d3js.org). The charts are rendering but as I have fixed the width and the height of the SVG Chart created using d3js to 960x480. If I do not use Jquery Mobile the charts are zoomable and scrollable, however in case of using charts with Jquery Mobile the charts are rendered but they are not scrollable and neither zoomable, hence the charts get cut out on mobile devices.

Is there a workaround to this?

```
  <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="areachart">
        <div data-theme="e" data-position="fixed" data-role="header"  data-id="header">
            <h3>
                Header
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" id="viz">
        </div>
        <div data-theme="e" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"  data-id="footer">
            <h3>
                Footer
            </h3>
        </div>
        <script>
         var header = localStorage.getItem("chartWizHeader");
         var footer = localStorage.getItem("chartWizFooter");

        $(document).live('pageinit',function(event){



            $('#areachart div[data-role="header"] h3').text(header);
            $('#areachart div[data-role="footer"] h3').text(footer);


            d3.json(sessionStorage.getItem("areaChart"), function(data) {

                d3.select("#viz").html("");

                sessionStorage.removeItem("areaChart");
                // Data is the Final Output.

                $.each(data, function(i, d) {
                  d.Year = +d.Year;
                  d.Sales = +d.Sales;
                  d.Expenses = +d.Expenses;
                });

                //Declare Margin.
                var margin = {top:10,left:50,right:30,bottom:20};

                //Declare height and width of the SVG.
                var height = 500 - margin.bottom - margin.top;
                var width  = 970 - margin.left - margin.right;

                //Define Scaling for x and y
                var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([d3.min(data,function(d){return d.Year}),d3.max(data,function(d){return d.Year})]).range([0,width]);
                var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,d3.max(data,function(d){
                        if(d.Sales < d.Expenses){
                            return d.Expenses;
                        }else{
                            return d.Sales;
                        }
                    })]).range([height,0]);

                // Both axis have to be defined.
                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().orient("bottom").scale(x).ticks(data.length);
                var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().orient("left").scale(y);

                // Create the lines.
                var line1 = d3.svg.line().x(
                        function(d){return x(d.Year);}
                ).y(function(d){return y(d.Sales);});
                var line2 = d3.svg.line().x(function(d){ return x(d.Year);}).y(function(d){return y(d.Expenses);});

                //Create the Area which has starting points.
                var area1 = d3.svg.area().x(line1.x()).y1(line1.y()).y0(y(0));

                var area2 = d3.svg.area().x(line2.x()).y1(line2.y()).y0(y(0));


                //Create the SVG Element.
                var svg = d3.select("#viz").append("svg").datum(data).attr("width",width + margin.left + margin.right).attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                            .append("g").attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")");

                //Add path of area.
                svg.append("path").attr("style"," fill: lightsteelblue;fill-opacity: 0.4;").attr("d",area1);

                //Add path of area.
                svg.append("path").attr("style","fill: #00FF00;fill-opacity: 0.4;").attr("d",area2);

                svg.append("g").attr("class","x axis").attr("transform","translate(0,"+height+")").call(xAxis);

                svg.append("g").attr("class","y axis").call(yAxis);

                svg.append("path").attr("style"," fill: none;stroke: steelblue;stroke-width: 1.5px;").attr("d",line1);


                });

        });
    </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the `viewport` meta tag?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

In case you are supporting iOS devices, check this [Zoom fixes: orientation change iOS bug and select/input zoom](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/04/13/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0/#features)

Comment: Yes I added that. The fix was to give the div in which the element was kept a "css style attribute" $("#divid").css("overflow-x","scroll");